# getting stack trace from separate thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a python program what uses Tkinter for windows and is running on several threads.  Occasionally it will freeze and when I stop it, I don't get a stack trace.  I tried getting the stack by running a separate thread with `traceback.print_stack()`, but this only prints the stack for that thread.

is there a way for me to get the stack trace from all threads, or will I need to check them each individually?

Is there a good way to continually monitor the stack so that i can figure out why my program becomes unresponsive?

Comment: Take a look at [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module. For Your particular case i wouldn't set_trace like in most common cases, but post_mortem function.

Comment: @brainovergrow I thought this was going to work, but python is crashing too, so it looks like its taking pdb and the stack with it when it goes down...

Comment: Hmm, if it is so then two other options - either (if on Linux), hook up to Your app with strace to get at least some partial information or - what seems to be much better idea - disable part by part some modules of Your application, and You find out what causes this behavior. Or run unittests, as everyone writes tests for their applications, right ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

SO the best thing I have found to do this is to put all the threads in a try loop, then when an exception occurs use `traceback` to print out the error.   I also try to give my threads name so that they will tell me who they are when they experience a problem.  An example is below.

```
import traceback
class mt_thread:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        thread.start_new_thread(self.thread_code,())

    def thread_code(self):
        try:
            "CODE HERE"
        except:
            print self.name,"ERROR"
            traceback.print_exc()

new_thread=my_thread("thread_1")
```